# Inverse Kinematics in BGE not working

Tags: game-engine, rigging, inverse-kinematics

I'm beginning in Blender and trying to create my first test game, but now I'm stuck in the creation of a aim system.

Basically I created a tank model and associated an armature in it. Then, I created a cube (IK_target) which gives the position where the tank should aim to. I used Inverse Kinematics to achieve this, and I actually did some progress.

When in Pose Mode, the Tank aims to wherever the Cube is, but when I run the game, the armature moves but the mesh didn't deform. Am I missing something?

I already used the actuator "Run Armature" in the armature, but it didn't work. 
I searched internet around and found this guy with a [similar problem](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?376608-Inverse-Kinematics-don-t-update-in-realtime), but I couldn't solve as he did.

Here is the [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5mi29knbbsi67k/tank_modelv3.blend?dl=0).

PS: Let me know if there's another way more sophisticated or simple to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just quoting one solution that Daedalus_MDW gave me in [another thread](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?411018-Inverse-Kinematics-in-BGE-not-working&p=3123404#post3123404).

> to solve your issue, you need to make the armature a parent of the mesh. but then collision wont work. heres how it should look.
>
> -> simple collision mesh (low poly invisible physics)
>
> -v> armature
>
> --v> visual mesh (pretty hires stuff)
>
> make sure everything is at (0,0,0) location, otherwise unusual things may occur.

It worked as expected :)